# Bad notification posted from package [Couldn't expand RemoteViews]

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My app uses custom contentView and contentBigView. Essentially it supports expanding notifications. I have a bug that causes the app to crash and it is only happens on a few devices. I can not reproduce this issue myself however this issue is persistent on the listed devices below.

I can see this is only happening on Android 4.2.x. Anyone have any ideas of a potential bug on Android?

**Devices**

- THL T100S [Android 4.2.2]
- Lenovo P780 (P780_ROW) [Android 4.2.1]
- Lenovo S820 (S820_ROW) [Android 4.2]
- Lenovo A766 [Android 4.2]

**Logcat**

```
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281): android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.android.DroidLiveLite: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.android.DroidLiveLite id=2131165283 tag=null score=0 notn=Notification(pri=0 contentView=com.android.DroidLiveLite/0x7f03004d vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 kind=[null]) user=UserHandle{0})
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5405)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:838)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
02-24 09:45:39.752 E/AndroidRuntime( 4281):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you found a solution for it please share it. Thanks!

Comment: @ZiadHalabi no solution found. Some devices seem to have a bad implementation of the Notifications APIs. I'm simply disabling the custom notifications on those devices reporting this error and using standard notifications.